# How Do I Prevent Template Flashes Using Meteor/Iron-Router/Spacebars?

Tags: javascript, meteor, sails.js, iron-router, spacebars

I want any user that is not authenticated to see a `home` template on the default `/` route (it is rendered inside a layout template called `main`). But if `currentUser` exists I want `/` to be something different (`dashboard` template to be exact).

Here is a solution that I came up with and it is working but has one major flaw that I will describe later.

1. I made an `app` template and set `/` route to it.
2. Inside `app` template all I have is this.

   ```
   <template name="app">
     {{#if currentUser}}
       {{> dashboard}}
     {{else}}
       {{> home}}
     {{/else}}
   </template>
   ```

It works as it should but every time I log in I can see a flash of `home` template before getting the `dashboard` one. I am using iron:router. What is a better approach for this situation?

Basically I want both `dashboard` and `home` being on the same route `/` depending if user is logged in or not. In Sails.js there was something called policies I could use. Is there anything that could enforce those rules on the router itself rather than using a helper template in between the two proper ones?

@edit:
I was thinking of three possible solutions:

1. Enforce those rules on the router itself instead of a helper template.
2. Force browser to wait with rendering `app` template before the logic is done and `dashboard` is properly loaded.
3. Show some kind of progress loader long enough so `dashboard` can load properly.

Comment: use a iron-router loading template. or check if user is logging in and then show a spinner?